# Possible to cache newsgroup message headers in Gnus

Tags: gnus, spacemacs

I'd like to start using Gnus to read mailing lists via nntp/Gmane.  Works fine so far, but each time I press `RET` on a group name in the `*Group*` buffer, Gnus seems to download a lot of data (in case of the org-mode list, some 30+M, which takes 10+ seconds).

Maybe I don't understand the workings of NNTP and Gnus properly, but shouldn't it be possible to somehow cache these data locally?  Waiting many seconds for entering a group seems to be a waste of time, especially since at this point, Gnus already knows the number of unread messages ...

Comment: @asjo Since the answer on the mailing list originally came from you, I'm happy to accept your answer if you want to give once here.

Comment: I think your summary is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem lies with the [default Spacemacs configuration](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/layers/%2Bemail/gnus/packages.el) I was using.

The solution was provided to me [on the Gnus mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.gnus.user/17930):

1. Set `gnus-fetch-old-headers` to `nil`
2. Set `gnus-keep-backlog` to `20`